# How can I fix the encoding of this bytes object to only keep the actual text and remove the '\x00\x05*\x00\x00\x0e\x00bjbj' in Python3?

Tags: python, string

**The Problem:**

I am using an API that retrieves the content of interest in the form of a bytes object.

The bytes object (myobj) has a value of:

```
myobj = b'\xd0\xcf\x11\xe0\xa1\xb1\x1a\xe1\x00\x00This is \rthe sentence \rI want to \rkeep.\r\r\x03\r\r\x04\r\r\x03\r\r\x04\x017\x00\x06'
```

**The Question:**

How do I only keep this: "This is the sentence I want to keep."

**What I've Tried:**

1: I tried decoding with UTF-8, however the output was the same as the input. I also tried 'ascii', 'utf-16', and 'utf-8'. If I remove the 'ignore' argument, i receive an error: UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xd0 in position 0: invalid continuation byte

```
myobj.decode('utf-8', 'ignore')
```

2: Tried using the printable function from string which returned almost the same output as the input.

```
import string
mystr =str(myobj)
print( ''.join(x for x in test2 if x in mystr.printable))
```

3: I also tried using strip() and replace to remove portions of the string, however, there are too many distinct characters.

Any suggestions would be great.

Thanks!

Comment: First of all you need some kind of rule what to keep and what to throw away. Variant 2 may work if you replace the "printable" string by something customized.

Comment: You aren't going to be able to solve this in any reliable way without knowing the actual format of the bytes you're receiving.  Surely this API you're using has some documentation available?  Perhaps it's actually a C `struct`, in which case you just need to retrieve bytes from a certain range.  Perhaps there are bytes that indicate the offset and/or length of the text of interest.  There's no way to tell with only a single example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've almost got it.  Combine options 1 and 2:

```
new_obj = ''.join(c for c in my_obj.decode('utf-8', 'ignore') if c.isprintable())
```

However, your `new_obj` will be:

```
'This is the sentence I want to keep.7'
```

That's because, near the end of `my_obj`, you've got `'\x017'`.  That's a byte with a value of 0x01 followed by the character `'7'`.

Comment: Is there a "crash course" on learning general encoding that you can refer me to? I run into these often and it's usually a long process of googling StackOverflow and searching for a previous questions...

Comment: Give [this](https://kunststube.net/encoding/) a try.